# JavaScript - if class list contains value from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to setup a filter on a database application, for lost property for a scout camp. The idea is the following:

The lost property items are logged into the database by reception as either 'Lost', 'Handed In', 'Owner Notified' or 'Returned' (meaning 4 lists generated from a table, with a status flag which is used to filter which list an item appears in).

At the top of each list, I have a form field (text) which I would like to use to filter the list, simply by the reception team member typing in some words that describe the item (eg, Jacket blue)

I've set a common class name to each row in the list table (a different one for each list, so listLost, listFound, listNotified, listReturned)

I've then used some of the database fields to add additional classes to the list (eg, item, colour, first name, surname - these are converted to UCASE to get around the case sensitive nature of JavaScript), so the final class might look like:

```
class="listLost JACKET BLUE FRED BLOGGS"
```

The reception team member can then type into the text field, something like 'Jacket Blue' and my JavaScript function is supposed to filter the list as follows:

the input from the text field is split into an array, using SPACE as the separator

it looks for all items in the page with a particular common class name (in this example, it would be listLost)

it then pages through the array comparing the class list for each (in this case, table row) with the array value and it if finds a match, the table row will be displayed, if not, it won't

Here's my JavaScript function:

```
function filterLostProperty(filterField,filterList)
{

var filterStr = document.getElementById(filterField).value;
var filterVals = filterStr.split(" ");
var filterItems = document.getElementsByClassName(filterList);
var displayCheck = 0

for (x = 0; x < filterItems.length; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < filterVals.length   ; y++)
    {
        if (filterItems[x].classList.contains(filterVals[y].toUpperCase()))
        {
            displayCheck++  
        }
    }
    if (displayCheck > 0)
    {
        filterItems[x].style.display = "table-row";
    }
    else
    {
        filterItems[x].style.display = "none";  
    }
}       

}
```

The form field has:

```
onChange="filterLostProperty('filterLost','listLost')
```

where filterLost is the ID of the text field from which the search string comes.

PROBLEM: it doesn't really filter in the way it should... some strings just generate everything, some bring up the item you wanted plus 2 you didn't, some don't generate anything at all. And when there is more than one word it goes even more weird.

Does anyone have any suggestions about where I might have gone wrong here? Or is my method here just too overly complicated and I'm missing a simple trick with something?

---

21.11.2017
So - I edited my function further after having a bit of an idea that I would instead of generating an Array of the filter text (as the array approach was only using the last entered word as the filter text), I would just create a string with AND between each one (using a replace function to replace SPACE with AND Operator), in the hope that it would do a 'If class list contains X and Y and Z then blah blah'...

I tested this with fixed values at first on my test page:

```
function manualFilter(filterList)

{

var filterItems = document.getElementsByClassName(filterList);

for (x = 0; x < filterItems.length; x++)
{

    {
        if (filterItems[x].classList.contains("WALLET" && "BLUE"))
        {
            filterItems[x].style.display = "table-row";
        }
        else
        {
            filterItems[x].style.display = "none";  
        }
    }
}

}
```

My test page is at https://bookings.springbank.org.uk/testFilter.asp and the test filter can be triggered by clicking the 'Manual Filter' button.
Problem is that when I do this, I get the row with WALLET BLUE in as expected (and not the row with WALLET BLACK which is good)... but I also get the row with JACKET BLUE (presumably because it's matched BLUE)... ideally, I don't want this to display.

If this can be made to work (effectively replacing the spaces from the text field entry with an AND operator to be interpreted by the IF statement)... the only other bit I'm not totally clear on (not being particularly proficient in JavaScript) is how I can do this dynamically from the function... presumably it's going to be a case of a certain number of consecutive quotes so that the && is interpreted as and AND operator and not simply as part of a string?

Comment: This is a tough one my friend, are there any errors you are getting? Have you tried using the "power" of console.log? Btw, I've done something like this, it isn't easy stuff. Arrays come with a sort function, it's a confusing but useful function.

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you. You need to share the cases which are failing for the above code.